# Can there be a C++ GUI Static library? But not a .dll?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, static-libraries

Yeah, I am wondering is there anything like that? Normally a static lib will be Console based, but what I need is a GUI library for suppose a `HelloWorld MessageBox` when I call `helloworld() func` in a console application.

Straight to the point, I need to integrate one GUI library (may be plugin - if plugin its a .dll right? OK anyway) in a Console Application.

I've tried looking at `Qt4 Plugin creation` but I think its only for Qt based applications? Please provide any links for my requirement. Thanks ...

Comment: at some operating systems dll are really rare.

Comment: What do you mean by **console based**? *Libraries* have nothing to do with your GUI, unless it's a GUI library. A library is a set of functions or a set of groups of functions.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Thanks for your comment. Yep I need to integrate GUI Library (.lib) in a Console based application...

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to compile your GUI libraries into a static library. That doesn't have anything at all to do with console or non-console applications.

Then, if you link your application with that, you get what you desire. But don't be surprised about the file size of your resulting program.

Comment: There's <http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/creating-and-using-static-libraries-in.html> for some basic understanding. Then there's <http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html> for some in-depth understanding. It's all Linux, though, I'm not at home on Windows.

If you already have a ".lib", which is a Windows static library, you should add it to your linker command, and that should be it, **theoretically**.

Comment: Well, a static library for returning minimal arithmetic operations I know, BUT I need `GUI based library (.lib) - atleast a Hello World MessageBox` to be linked to a `Simple Console based app - like #include<stdio.h>
int main(){
helloworld();} //extern present in that GUI library`

Comment: What I'm asking is **How to create a .lib that displays Hello World MessageBox** when I call it from a **Console based application**...

Comment: You probably do not want to create a static QT-based library including QT itself, since this would require a commercial QT license. You need to compile dynamic for QT-oss-library. But generally nothing will stop you from building a UI-Library for your console app and link to it (even statically)

Comment: @SebastianLange Thank you :) But can you give a small example of GUI Static Library for example a `Hello World Message Box` window (which is cross platform)?

Comment: It's quite hard to post an example of a "GUI static library". You'll need to find one you like yourself, compile it and link it into a  static library. From your questions, it seems you haven't even chosen a GUI lib you want to use. There's a lot of them out there. BTW, having a statically linked library does not make it "cross-platform", that's yet another totally different point.

Comment: @Sven OK... I tried my friend but didn't got any... Can u plz take a few minutes of pain and let me know the so called "GUI static library" ??

Comment: Qt, wxWigets, gtk, just to name a few, are all "GUI libraries". You'll have to choose one of those, and program your application using its API. Then, if you compile one of these "GUI libraries" into a static library, and link your application statically with it, you have what you desire.